# Trouble with Cross Domain Iframes on IE8: changing parent.location forces new popup window. if on a click event, it works as expected

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I'm having a lot of trouble getting cross domain iframe communication working.

It's working on Firefox and Chrome, but on Internet Explorer, it only works in **some** ways:

If the `parent.location = 'new_hash';` is not encompassed in an onClick event, it forces the parent frame to open a new popup window. If it is in an onClick event, the cross domain fragment identifier trick works. What gives?

Sounds like I need to ***understand*** javascript..

---

**Edit to comments:** parent.location.href and parent.location have the same behavior.

It seems to be my specific browser IE 8.0.7600.16385 reading the hash change as a popup. I'd like to hear if anybody else has experienced something like this.

### Creates popup in parent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
parent.location = 'http://example.com#new_hash';
</script>
```

shows a "popup blocked" dialog in IE8. If I let the popups open, they infinitely open popups.

### Does not create popup in parent:

```
<a onClick="parent.location='http://example.com#new_hash'">clicky</a>
```

or

```
$(function() { 
 $("mybutton").click( function() { 
   parent.location='http://example.com#new_hash';
});
```

Does not create popup in parent.

### My real example

Mine needs the parent.location=newhash to fire when its own hash has a certain value. I essentially have a :

```
setInterval(function() { 
 if (location.hash == 'something')
    {
      parent.location='http://example.com#new_hash';
    }  
}, 500);
```

What's going on? How can I tackle this problem?  Why does it work when tied to a click event but not if the statement runs on its own? The specific example i'm working on is at http://www.grovemade.com/products/test at v.04

I'm actively messing around here so it may become outdated..

**On Firefox and Chrome,** the parent frame is modified from no hash, to #xdm-success, to #handshake-complete.

On IE8, #xdm-success forces a new page to open.

Thank you!

Comment: i've tested your example in the domain you gave but I didn't get any pop-ups in IE8 or IE7.  It works the same way as firefox and chrome except the background is white in IEs

Comment: Ooh! Interesting. I wonder whats up!? 

Is this a well known problem on some IE8s? 8.0.7600.16385

I wonder what I should do... if on "some" IE8s, the site would infinitely create popups, that is.. very bad press. People will be chapped.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing, but it only occurs for me when the parent window is https.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be setting `parent.location.href` instead of `parent.location`? I wasn't aware the latter worked at all...

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the comment. It doesn't make a difference unfortunately. Behavior is the same on IE, Chrome and Firefox. 

I tested the base, simple example too: an iframe with <script>parent.location.href</script>

If it's in a click event, it works as expected. If not, it creates popups.. : (

Comment: Here's some other things you can try... set the hash directly: `parent.location.hash='new_hash';` or use location.replace: `parent.location.replace('http://example.com#new_hash')`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Setting parent.location.hash would give me a permission denied for cross domain issues. parent.location.replace gives me the same popup problem. 

It looks to be unique to my browser.. I tried another IE8 that works just fine. 

Now I have to track down how often this happens on various IE8s.

Comment: ^ The joys of javascript and internet explorer

Comment: Ah, it's cross-domain? That's probably the issue. Does this happen when it's not cross-domain? Does it happen in IE9? If (1:no, 2:yes) then it's probably by design, to defeat XSS attempts. One of IE's zillion security settings, maybe?

Comment: Yeah, it's cross domain. BUT, cross domain works IF its in an onClick event <a onClick> or jquery Click. That's why I'm half stumped, half VERY curious about how these things work.

I wish it would at least /fail/ instead of create an infinite series of popups for the user, like we're a spam site of the old ages.  -- am now going through the security settings.

Comment: I will try actually simulating the click event, since it works there! yaay, I have high hopes.

Comment: Didn't work. document.getElementById('test').click(); generates a popup on the parent. Actually clicking on the button silently updates the hash.

IDing the problem seems to be in there.. What's the difference between function X being called by a click event, as opposed to the initial parsing?


I'm glad I see a light though -- as long as it works during the click event, I can probably work around that and pass a session ID of the iframe to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think for legacy browsers you can just load another iframe inside the iframe and use a cookie to obtain the hash.